# Why does scrollTop not respond?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The other jQuery scripts on the page are working fine, just not scrollTop, I could even get it to work on https://jsfiddle.net/ivolong/tyvusdte/ just not on my website, which is using JQuery 3.2.1.

In between script tags in the body I have:

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#slide2").offset().top
        }, 3000);
    });


    $("#button2").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#slide1").offset().top
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Then I have:

```
<div class="slide" id="slide1">

        <p id="title">Title</p>

        <div id="specialText">

            <p>Line 1.</p>
            <p>Line 2.</p>
            <p>Line 3.</p>
            <p>Line 4.</p>

        </div>

        <button class="button" id="button1">&#8595;</button>

    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="slide2">

        <p id="title">Title</p>

        <div id="text">

            <p>Line 5.</p>
            <p>Line 6.</p>
            <p>Line 7.</p>
            <p>Line 8.</p>

        </div>

        <button class="button" id="button2">&#8595;</button>

    </div>
```

But it doesn't respond when the button is clicked

Comment: it it giving error in console 'Cannot read property 'top' of undefined' in 
ExtendedProject.php .Check it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the javascript code is above the html code. At that point when the javascript code is interpreted, there are not buttons rendered which leads to no event handler being attached.

You can fix this by placing you javascript code under you html code, or like correctly in a comment below mentioned: by wrapping your code inside jQueries document.ready function which will look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button1").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#slide2").offset().top
        }, 3000);
    });

    $("#button2").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#slide1").offset().top
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```